# Found main Category based on sum groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Could you please support me how to solve this problem below.

I trying to fing a some kind of main cattegory based on groupby and look how cateory have de more high value.

I have the dataframe below.

```
>> USER    PROCESS    HOURS_WORKED
>> 0    USER1    PROCESS1    1
>> 1    USER1    PROCESS2    2
>> 2    USER1    PROCESS3    3
>> 3    USER2    PROCESS1    1
>> 4    USER2    PROCESS2    5
>> 5    USER2    PROCESS3    3
```

And i apply the groupby mehotd based on USER and PROCESS.

`dfg = df1.groupby(['USER','PROCESS']).sum()`

My target is dataframe below.

```
USER    MAIN_PROCESS
USER1   PROCESS3
USER2   PROCESS2
```

Could there are any method or function in groupby that make this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df[df.groupby(['USER']).HOURS_WORKED.rank("dense", ascending=False).eq(1)]
```

result:

```
    USER   PROCESS  HOURS_WORKED
2  USER1  PROCESS3             3
4  USER2  PROCESS2             5
```

When rank of `HOURS_WORKED` in descending order per `USER` is equal to 1 it indicates 'main process'.

Comment: Thank you so much my friend. It will help me a lot.